# Susy 2 gutters not appearing

Tags: susy-sass, susy

For some reason I'm not seeing gutters appearing in Susy 2. Any ideas why these might not be appearing? I have my map set, shouldn't the spans pick up the gutter settings by default?

```
  section{
  @include full;
  @include span(6 at 4 of 12 isolate);
   @include gutters();
  .serviceBox{
   @include span(first 2 of 6);
  // display: inline-block;
    height:span(2 of 6);
  }//serviceBox
  .volunteerBox{
    @include span(2 of 6);
    display: inline-block;
    height:span(2 of 6);
  }//serviceBox
    .partnerBox{
       @include span(last 2 of 6);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height:span(2 of 6);
  }//serviceBox
```

Map

```
$susy: 

 columns: 12,
  container: 100%,
  gutters: 1/4,
  gutter-position: inside,
  debug:(
image: hide,
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `gutter-position` set to `inside` which means you gutters appear as padding on the spans. From what I can tell, it looks like your padding is there — maybe you were expecting margins? You'll need to use `before`, `after`, or `split` gutters in order to see space between the spans. You can change that globally in your setup, or locally where you call the span (`span(2 of 6 after)`).